# How can the Redux form render a Field of Arrays before the render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to execute a very simple example with ReduxForm and I have two functions before the render, but one of the functions call another as a component props, but then it is undefined. I tried to bind the this but it still dont recognise it.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

class Page4 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.simpleField.bind(this)
  }

  simpleField(field) {
  const { meta }  = field
  return (
    <div className='form-group'>
      <label>{field.label}</label>
      <input
        className='form-control'
        {...field.input}
      />
    </div>
  )
 }
  // This function cannot reach the simpleField component
  myFields(field) {
    let optiosArray = [
      {'label':'Option 1', 'value':'1'},
      {'label':'Option 2', 'value':'2'}
     ]
    return(
      optionsArray.map((option, key) => {
        <Field
          label= {option.label}
          value= {option.value}
          name={option.value}
          component={this.simpleField}
        />
      })
    )
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FieldArray
        name='test'
        label='label'
        component={this.myFields}
      />
   </div>
  )  
 }
}

const validate = (value) => {
 const errors = ''
 return errors
}

export default reduxForm({
 validate,
 form: 'Page4'
})(Page4)
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. Also you said that you bound your own functions but i can't see where you did this. You can't access your instance via `this` inside your functions without binding them.

Comment: Hi. Edited and fixed: I still get the same error if I bind this. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'simpleField' of undefined

Comment: Okay then what exactly is the error? Can you please add it's exact text to your question?

Comment: You did not bind the function `myFields()` which is actually the function that needs to access `this`. Also it is best practice to bind functions in the constructor rather than in the render cycle because that way it would be rebound on every render. See my answer on how to bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access `this.simpleFields`, binding the `this.myFields` in the constructor is good enough.

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.myFields = this.myFields.bind(this)
  }
```

**this.myFields =** this.myFields.bind(this)

I think you are using the FieldArray incorrectly. I've modified the code so that it will give you an idea on how FieldArray should be used. Working jsFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/4u3hk7kg/

```
class Page4 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.myFields = this.myFields.bind(this)
  }

   simpleField = (field) => {
    const { input: { value } } = field
        return (
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input type="text" name={field.input.name} onChange={field.input.onChange} value={value} />  
        </div>
      )
 }

  myFields({ fields }) {
        return (<div>{fields.map((option, key) => {
        return (<div key={key}>
          <Field
            name={option}
            component={this.simpleField}
          />
        </div>)
      })}</div>)
    }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FieldArray
        name='listOfTextFields'
        component={this.myFields}
      />
   </div>
  )  
 }
}

const validate = (value) => {
 const errors = ''
 return errors
}

const MyTextFields = reduxForm({
 validate,
 form: 'Page4'
})(Page4)
```

And when calling the component, you should do the following.

```
<MyTextFields initialValues={{ listOfTextFields: [ 'Text 1','Text 2' ] }}/>
```

Comment: Yes. I agree. The reason my code is not working is due to it is not following the correct logic approach needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You did bind the wrong function. You are trying to access `this` in your `myFields()` function. Therefore you have to bind this one and not `simpleField()`.

You have to bind your methods ether in the constructor:

```js
class Page4 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myFields.bind(this);
    }

    myFields(...) {
        ....
    }
}
```

or if you use babel and ES6, you can use an arrow function. This way it will be automatically bound:

```
class Page4 extends Component {
    myFields = (field) => {
        ....
    };
}
```

Do not bind functions in the render cycle because that means you would create a new callback on every render.

Comment: I think we are close. But still get undefined.

Comment: @LucasOliveiraSilva but then it is not `this` that is undefined. Post the full text of the error you are getting...

Comment: Also you have a typo in your code `let optiosArray = [...]`. Please fix this too.